# Kill mono-service

Tags: c#, mysql, mono

I started an application with:

```
mono-service app.exe
```

Now the problem is that I can't find it. I tried finding the process, but I can't find it. When I try to start the application it gives me the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
```

Comment: How are you running it? Does mono-service.exe doesn't have parameter to terminate the application? Alternatively, you can stop/start the mysql instance/service.

Comment: I tried restarting the mysql service, but nothing happened. Also I'm running it under Linux. I tried searching for the process, but I can't find any mono process.

Comment: maybe there is none and your app ended without releasing some unmanaged resources did you dispose of all disposable objects (consider success path and all exception paths)?

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono-service - see this link. I am sorry, I haven't worked on mono/linux. Instead of restarting mysql, see if you can shut it down.

Comment: @Rafal It's possible, because it's running as service. The problem is that I can't the process and after I killed all mysqld processes the problem still appears.

Comment: @HerpaMoTeH if you say so. I don't really know how services are handled on linux but it is very unlikely that there is no process for it to be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the error message. It isn't complaining about another process, it's complaining about a problem in the program you are trying to execute which happens even if only a single instance is running. You must have a bug that tries to reuse a connection that's still busy. See also various other questions about the problem, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440168/c-sharp-mysql-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connectio).

Comment: The problem turned out to be very confusing. The problem was that I was trying to truncate a table after I have updated it.