# C# MySQL Query in DataReader loop query

Tags: c#, mysql, datareader

I have a method in C# which should get some data from mysql and then insert this data in another table.
The problem is that no matter what I try i get `another datareader is open`.
I tried using the `using` statement, but with no success, maybe I do it wrong.
How to do that?

```
public void MethodName(List<string> objects)
{
    foreach(string Object in objects){
        SQLActions.Initialize();
        SQLActions.SQL_Open();
        MySqlDataReader queryData = SQLActions.SQL_Query("SELECT...query...");

        MySqlDataReader objectsData = SQLActions.SQL_Query("Another select....");
        SQLActions.SQL_NonQuery("Insert...");
        while(queryData.Read()){
            SQLActions.SQL_NonQuery("Another Insert...");
        }
        SQLActions.SQL_Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code would be very helpful.

Comment: Mention your code here.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using the same connection for the DataReader and the ExecuteNonQuery. This is not supported, according to MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.80).aspx

Check this:

[C# mySQL There is already an open DataReader associated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440168/c-sharp-mysql-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connectio)

From Microsoft:

You should always call the Close method when you have finished using the DataReader object.

Comment: I cheched that before and I'm not sure if this will help. I want to insert when the reading process is going. I will not be able to read if I close the connection.

Comment: Can I use two parallel connections?