# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have below code and I am getting exception

> "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection
>   which must be closed first".

I am using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express and Microsoft Access 2007 for this project.

```
namespace Database1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection connection;
        public void connect()
        {
            connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\PBName1.accdb;Data Source=C:\Users\bvino_000\Downloads\PBName1.accdb");
            connection.Open();
        }
        public void close_connection()
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
       connect();

        OleDbDataReader reader = null;
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from  PBInfo", connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(reader[1].ToString());
        }
        close_connection();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        string s = "";
        s = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        connect();
        string sql = "SELECT PBSize FROM PBInfo where PBName=" + " '" + s + "' ";

        try
        {
            OleDbDataReader reader = null;
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection);
            reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                command.ExecuteReader();
            }

            reader.Close();
            command.Dispose();
            close_connection();

            if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }

            label2.Text = command.ExecuteReader().ToString();
            listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.GetBaseException();
        }
        finally
        {
            close_connection();
        }          
    }
```

}
}

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440168/c-sharp-mysql-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connectio

Comment: You call ExecuteReader two times in the Button_Click event. And the next `label2.Text = command.ExecuteReader().ToString()` makes no sense

Answer (score 4):

The reader in the Form's constructor is not closed. You should consider working with the using construct to avoid this:

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
{
   ... 
}
```

Comment: Thankz for reply, but actually i am new to this. Where should i use this "using construct"??

Comment: replace the declaration and assignment of the reader with the `using` construct and enclose the reading part (i.e. the loop) with braces so that the `using` block is active for that part. Also consider reading about `using` on MSDN online. BTW: I am quite new as well.

Comment: Sir, i have tried a lot but um getting no way near in getting the error removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to close reader on form contructor. When you execute button1_Click a reader is allready open

```
 public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();
   connect();

    OleDbDataReader reader = null;
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from  PBInfo", connection);
    reader = command.ExecuteReader();


    while (reader.Read())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader[1].ToString());
    }
      **reader.Close();
      command.Dispose();**
    //close_connection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`Retrieving Data Using a DataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> Note that while a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use
>   exclusively by that DataReader. You cannot execute any commands for
>   the Connection, including creating another DataReader, **until the
>   original DataReader is closed.**

Either you should close the current [`OleDbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or define different [`OleDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) for each [`OleDbDataReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Sir, i have tried but um not getting that. Plzz help with the code.