# C# & SQL Server : fetch data and then delete returns error

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have the following script to fetch me some data from a database and then remove it:

```
public void checkDB()
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM dbt";

    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

    SqlDataReader reader;
    int id = -1;

    using (reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                String data= reader["sdata"].ToString();
                Order o = new Order(reader["sdata"].ToString());
                o.prepareForScript();
                id = reader.GetSqlInt32(1).Value;
            }

            reader.Close();
    }

    if (id != -1)
    {
        string removeQuery = "DELETE FROM data WHERE ID=" + id;

        SqlCommand removeCMD = new SqlCommand(removeQuery, conn);

        removeCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This code results in an exception

> unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

with the aditional information that a reader is already associated with this connection. However as you can see the reader is both closed and inside a using loop meaning that it should definitly be closed. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440168/exception-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connection-w

Comment: Try wrapping your SQL commands in a using also.
see 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985876/sqlconnection-sqlcommand-sqldatareader-idisposable

Comment: May be the `conn` problem. Have you tried to close the conn after SELECT query & open for DELETE query.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @Marc_s I'm aware of the risk however I'm pulling an int from a database and then sending it back for deletion that shouldn't be a risk here right?

Comment: Also take a look at the OUTPUT keyword. You can do your delete and return the deleted rows all at the same time.

Comment: @Thijser: just get in the habit of doing it *the right way*! Don't do it with parameters once, and without another time - just use parametrized queries **always** to be on the safe side!

Comment: @Thijser: [see what Jon Skeet has to say on the topic](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/) - and takes his words to heart !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to dispose first `SqlCommand` as below :

```
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
        SqlDataReader reader;
        int id = -1;

        using (reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {


                String data= reader["sdata"].ToString();
                Order o = new Order(reader["sdata"].ToString());
                o.prepareForScript();
                id = reader.GetSqlInt32(1).Value;
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
}
```

Or

enable `MultipleActiveResultSets`. This way SQL Server allows several open data readers on a single connection.

But i would suggest not to use your SQL statements together to avoid `Sql Injection`.