# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException - There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and asp.net-mvc 4, I'm getting a Mysql.Data Exception and I couldn't find any related thread on google.

Here's the error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Here's my controller's method:

```
// GET: api/Partenaires_prestations
[Authorize]
[Route("api/Partenaires_prestations")]
public List<PartenaireMapItem> GetPartenairesWithPrestations()
{
     Random rnd = new Random();

     var queryString = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

     var prestation = queryString.FirstOrDefault();

     return db.Partenaires
         .Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem {
             IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
             FirstName = p.FirstName,
             LastName = p.LastName,
             NomComplet = p.LastName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + ". " + p.FirstName,
             Type = p.Type,
             DureeMin = 50,
             Lat = p.Lat,
             Lng = p.Lng,
             ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
             SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace,
             ADomicile = p.ADomicile,

             Notes = p.NoteClientPartenaires,
             Prestations = new List<string>(p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation))
         }).ToList();
}
```

Thanks to anyone who will take the time to read/answer my post.

Comment: How is your: `db` variable initialized?

Comment: does your connection allow multiple active result sets?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro how can I see that ?

Comment: @Stefan  ```private UphairDbEntities db = new UphairDbEntities();```

Comment: it should be part of your connection string

Comment: @PierrickMartellière: are you calling `Dispose()` on it anywhere?

Comment: I tried to add it already on my connection string but got an error: "The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString. - Keyword not supported.
↵Parameter name: multipleactiveresultsets" I'm adding my connection String to my orginal post.

Comment: @Stefan yes it is called in ```protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }```

Comment: MySQL may not support MARS. It certainly has a history of not supporting it, not sure about new versions. If you remove the assignments to `Notes` and `Prestations` does it work?

Comment: If  your context were disposed you would not get the error you are getting.

Comment: I did get an Out of Memory error, now the method is not returning anymore... I'm quite lost

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are running multiple queries, on the same connection, simultaneously.

The error is a result of that. You can choose to allow it, or fix it.

Lets fix it (disclaimer; it's a bit of a guess here):

In your code, you have 2 queries actively running on your connection. You can easely fix it by changing the `AsEnumerable` to `ToList`

```
db.Partenaires
         .Where(p => p.PartenairePrestations.Any(pp => pp.Prestation.NomPrestation == prestation.Value))
         //note: the change is here
         .ToList()
         .Select(p => new PartenaireMapItem {
             IdPartenaire = p.IdPartenaire,
             FirstName = p.FirstName,
             LastName = p.LastName,
             NomComplet = p.LastName.Substring(0,1).ToUpper() + ". " + p.FirstName,
             Type = p.Type,
             DureeMin = 50,
             Lat = p.Lat,
             Lng = p.Lng,
             ImageUrl = p.ImageUrl,
             SeDeplace = p.SeDeplace,
             ADomicile = p.ADomicile,

             Notes = p.NoteClientPartenaires,
             Prestations = new List<string>(p.PartenairePrestations.Select(y => y.Prestation.NomPrestation))
         }).ToList();
```

**Be advised**, the `ToList` will force the query to run against the DB directly. The `AsEnumerable` will deffer execution until it's being enumerated. So the `ToList` will prevent the "open data reader error" at this specific location.

While enumerating, my guess is, that your code triggers another query, which results in the given error.

---

As an alternative you could drop the `AsEnumerable` altogether so a single query will be build. But note, that in that scenario, all functions used in the query must be translated to SQL.

---

Here's a related one; about a datareader, which is basically the same:

[Exception: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440168/exception-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connection-w#7404092)